# Swapping out .png images in Xcode 5 iOS 7 not working

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, xcode5, expressionengine

I am taking over and revamping an old app at work. The buttons are connected to Expression Engine but it looks to me that the image that servers as the background for these bottoms are coded. I want to change this image so I found the following code and made the following change. The Image that the app had used for a back ground image on the buttons was called navbar.png. I arrived at that conclusion because I went through looking at the images in the file I got off the git repository till I saw one that looked right and then I did a search in the app's code, found it, and replaced it with the new one. The new one has been imported into the app's resources folder (where all it's media is stored). I see no mention on any .png files in the function that draws the view. and there are no other instances of navbar.png in any other file in the project I even removed it from the resources folder and went through all the other files in the resources folder looking for others that look like the one the app keeps using as the background image. Any help would be appreciated, I am very green when it comes to iOS so please feel free to assume I am an idiot thank you in advance.

```
//Navbar loading after didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
/* 
-(void)customizeAppearance
{
    UIImage *navbar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navbar forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:242/255.0 green:102/255.0 blue:84/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
}
*/


-(void)customizeAppearance
{
    UIImage *navbar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-blnak.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navbar forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:242/255.0 green:102/255.0 blue:84/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
}
```

Comment: I needed to edit the .xib file. What little iOS experience I have has not used these since I have only done story boarding. I know I clicked around on the .xib file for "viewController.xib" but I was not able to make any of the needed changes to it. what I needed to do was control+click on the file and choose open as source file and and from there import the the new image file and un-import the the old file and then I just found all the places in the source file where the old file was referenced and replaced it there.